# Auto Select values <select multiple="multiple">

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am new to coding but trying to help myself. If any one can suggest would be great.

I am using a plugin which is creating a below form. I checked this by inspecting elements on browser.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="attendee_information_fields[]" id="attendee_information_fields" class="event-manager-multiselect" data-no_results_text="No results match" attribute="" data-multiple_text="Select Some Options" style="display: none;">
        <option value="full-name">Full name</option>
        <option value="email-address">Email address</option>
        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
        <option value="location">Location</option>
        <option value="gender">Gender</option>
        <option value="age">Age</option>
        <option value="terms-conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</option>
        <option value="become-a-cfp-camper">Become a CFP Camper</option>
</select>
```

This is a mandatory field. What I want is the option values should auto selected with values `terms-conditions` and `become-a-cfp-camper`. For this, I am writing below code in my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
if($_POST['attendee_information_fields']) { echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#attendee_information_fields').click( function() {
    $('select#terms-conditions > option').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('select#become-a-cfp-camper > option').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>";
}
```

Nothing seems to happen and I am clueless. Can anyone help how can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$('select#terms-conditions > option')` is trying to find all `<option>` elements inside a `<select id="terms-conditions">`. You don't have that; instead, you have a `<select id="attendee_information_fields">` which contains a `<option value="terms-conditions">`.

To select that option, you need to use `$('select#attendee_information_fields option[value=terms-conditions]')`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The problem is, where should I paste this function? Because I don't know from where this form is being generated by the plugin so I am trying to echo this in functions.php file (please check my original post) and nothing happens. Any idea where should I paste this code to accomplish results? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues to your problem:

1. Your jQuery is selecting a `<select>` element with IDs (`$('select#terms-conditions > option')`), when what you want to do is actually to search for nested `<option>` elements with the value that matches, e.g. (`$('select option[value="terms-conditions"]')`)
2. You are using `.attr()` instead of `.prop()` to set boolean attributes

My solution is as follow:

1. Listen to modifications on the `<select>` field (we try to avoid listening to click events on input elements). This is done by binding the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method
2. Go through all the `<option>` elements found in the element (referenced by `$(this).find('option')`)
3. We filter this collection using jQuery's [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to only return elements whose value attribute are found in the array. The array should contain the values that you are interested in selecting: evaluated using the simply [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method in native JS: when the index return is 0 or more, it means the value is in your array. The array you want to look at will be `['become-a-cfp-camper', 'terms-conditions']`.
4. To the filtered selection of `<option>` elements, we simply programatically select them using [`.prop('selected', true)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#attendee_information_fields').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option').filter(function() {
      return ['become-a-cfp-camper', 'terms-conditions'].indexOf($(this).val()) > -1;
    }).prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  height: 200px; /* Just to have a better view */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple name="attendee_information_fields[]" id="attendee_information_fields" class="event-manager-multiselect" data-no_results_text="No results match" attribute="" data-multiple_text="Select Some Options">
        <option value="full-name">Full name</option>
        <option value="email-address">Email address</option>
        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
        <option value="location">Location</option>
        <option value="gender">Gender</option>
        <option value="age">Age</option>
        <option value="terms-conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</option>
        <option value="become-a-cfp-camper">Become a CFP Camper</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The problem is, where should I paste this function? Because I don't know from where this form is being generated by the plugin so I am trying to echo this in functions.php file (please check my original post) and nothing happens. Any idea where should I paste this code to accomplish results? Many thanks

Comment: @AtharK Are you using WordPress? If that's the case you shouldn't be modifying your theme's functions.php file. Use `wp_enqueue_script()` instead. If the select dropdown is being generated dynamically, you might want to leverage on event bubbling instead of binding the change event listener directly, i.e. use `$(document).on('change', '#attendee_information_fields', function() { ... });`. All these are however somewhat beyond the scope of your original question, because the original question is simply a piece of jQuery code with incorrect logic and selectors.

Comment: yes I am using wordpress and I am using wp_enqueue_script(). But I am not that expert in coding. Thanks for suggestion though. Can you elaborate on the above as in what to use inside the function? Many thanks for your help.